# Использование OracleDataReader для выборки данных из бд Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle

Смотрю код в отладчике, и при извлечении данных из БД с помощью дата ридера возникает следующая проблема. Привожу код.

```
using (OracleDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (rdr.Read())
    {
        int recordId515 = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["ID"]);
        Journal journal515 = new Journal(515);
        journal515.ReadData(recordId515);
        JournalTable jTbl515 = journal515.Tables[0];
        jTbl515.SetFieldValue(recordId515, "GOTOVN_SERT", enDate);
        //сохранение созданной записи в БД
        jTbl515.SaveRecordToDatabase(recordId515);
    }
}
```

Выполняю следующие действия:

- Прохожу пошаговой отладкой строку `int recordId515 = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["ID"]);` и останавливаюсь.
- С помощью инструмента квик вотч смотрю `rdr["ID"]` там находится айдишник. Грубо говоря число из 7-8 цифр.
- В следующий момент не проходя ни шага дальше отладкой. Навожу курсор на rdr и раскрываю его что бы там посмотреть этот элемент. Вижу информацию что в ридере пусто и "Перечисление не дало результатов".
- И ещё раз (опять же ни шагу дальше отладчиком) смотрю в квик вотче `rdr["ID"]`. И там уже не айдишник который я видел несколько секунд назад, а exception.

Как такое возможно? Если я решу посмотреть что в ридере до прохождения строчки `int recordId515 = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["ID"]);` отладчиком, тогда реально и выпадет экзепшен. Что это такое? Я уже не понимаю в чём тут прикол. Может кто то видел такое?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Навожу курсор на rdr и раскрываю его что бы там посмотреть этот элемент. Вижу информацию что в ридере пусто и "Перечисление не дало результатов".

Предположу, что отладчик Visual Studio при отображении `DataReader` вызывает метод `Read` повторно и т.о. переводит его на следующую строку, которой нет. Воспроизвести ошибку сейчас не могу, но, по крайней мере, [люди уже жаловались на подобное поведение дебаггера в прошлом](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6493955/datareader-has-rows-and-data-trying-to-read-from-it-says-no-data-is-present). Для проверки можете попробовать раскрыть `rdr` до `if (rdr.Read())` и проверить выполниться ли условие вообще после этого.

Как исправить не знаю, менять код ради отладки простого момента я бы не стал. Гораздо легче не обращаться к `rdr` через отладчик. Добавьте в watches значение `rdr["ID"]` этого должно быть достаточно.